# Master theorem - issue on proof

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to proof by myself the 2<sup>nd</sup> case of the master theorem (Cormen et al)

If $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$ then $T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a}\log_b n)$

I know that the recurrence for $T(n)$ can be expanded to

$$
T(n) = n^{\log_b a}T(1) + \sum_{i=0}^{\log_b n - 1}a^i f\left(\frac{n}{b^i}\right)\label{1}\tag{1}
$$

In the book they jump directly to

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\log_b n - 1}a^i f\left(\frac{n}{b^i}\right) = \Theta\left( 
\sum_{i=0}^{\log_b n - 1}a^i \left(\frac{n}{b^i}\right)^{\log_b a} \right)\label{2}\tag{2}
$$

and the proof follows...

I can't understand why this last equation is true.

If $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$ then, by definition, there exist $c_1, c_2 > 0$ and $n_0 \geq 0$ so that

$$
c_1 · n^{\log_b a} \leq f(n) \leq c_2 · n^{\log_b a},\quad n \geq n_0
$$

I was tempted to form the series

$$
c_1 · n^{\log_b a} \leq f(n) \leq c_2 · n^{\log_b a},\quad n \geq n_0\\
a · c_1 · (n/b)^{\log_b a}\leq a·f(n/b) \leq a·c_2 · (n/b)^{\log_b a},\quad n \geq b·n_0\\
a^2 · c_1 · (n/b^2)^{\log_b a}\leq a^2·f(n/b^2) \leq a^2·c_2 · (n/b^2)^{\log_b a},\quad n \geq b^2·n_0\\
\vdots
$$

and so on until the exponent equals $\log_b n - 1$. But in that case I would obtain the condition $b \geq n_0$

I know I am misunderstanding something.

In ($\ref{1}$) $i$ depends on $n$, so I don't think we can go to ($\ref{2}$) directly (it is totally valid if $i$ were fixed and doesn't depend on $n$).

Please, help me.

Comment: I have found this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434755/asymptotic-equalities-in-master-theorem-proof) that poses quite the same question but it is still open.

Comment: Which edition of Cormen et al.'s "Introduction to Algorithms" is this?  I'm asking because I seem to remember that the master theorem proof varies a bit between editions.

Comment: For reference, see question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404175/11994 for a quote of the relevant part from Cormen et al., 2nd Ed., where they say
"
$$g(n) = \sum^{\log_b n - 1}_{j=0} a^j f(n/b^j) \;\;\;\;\;(4.7)$$ Under the assumption that $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$ for case 2, we have that $f(n/b^j) = \Theta((n/b^j)^{\log_b a})$. Substituting into equation (4.7) yields $$g(n) = \Theta\left(\sum^{\log_b n - 1}_{j = 0} a^j \left(\frac n {b^j}\right)^{\log_b a}\right) \;\;\;\;\; (4.9)$$
"
The question seems to be about the details of "Substituting \[...\] yields".

Comment: The reasoning in the book is as follows:\begin{align}\quad&
f(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_b a})
\\\Rightarrow\quad\\&
f(n/b^j)=\Theta((n/b^j)^{\log_b a})
\\\Rightarrow\quad\\&
\sum^{\log_b n-1}_{j=0} a^j f(n/b^j)=\Theta\left(\sum^{\log_b n-1}_{j=0}a^j\left(n/{b^j}\right)^{\log_b a}\right)
\end{align}Which of these steps is unclear? To your credit, as far as I can see in the book (3rd Ed., which is the only one I have at hand right now), neither of these is mentioned in the preceding Chapter 3, "Growth of Functions". So there is a lot hidden in this "we have that" and "Substituting \[...\] yields".

Comment: The step

$$
f(n/b^j) = \Theta((n/b^j)^{\log_b a})
$$

I know that if $b^j$ is a constant, then this is totally true (for n suficiently large). But, I'm not sure that this is still true if $j$ depends on $n$.

Because the summation is from 0 to $\log_b n - 1$

Comment: I think that if I can demonstrate

$$
f(n)=\Theta\left(h(n)\right) \Rightarrow \sum_{j=0} ^{g(n)} \beta_j f\left(n/\alpha_j\right) = \Theta\left(  \sum_{j=0} ^{g(n)} \beta_j h\left(n/\alpha_j\right)  \right)
$$

then everything will be clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt at an answer in a 'calculational' style.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\opnohint}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\subcalch}[1]{\\ \quad & \quad #1 \\ \quad &}
\newcommand{\subcalc}{\quad \begin{aligned} \quad & \\ \bullet \quad & }
\newcommand{\endsubcalc}{\end{aligned} \\ \\ \cdot \quad &}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\asymEq}[1]{=\Theta\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\asymLe}[1]{=O\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\forallle}{\forall_{l.e.}}
%$

## Two steps, two properties

The reasoning in Cormen et al. (in the 2nd and 3rd Editions: the proof for case 2 of Lemma 4.3) is
$$\calc
    f(n) \asymEq{n^{\log_b a}}
\opnohint\then
    f(n/b^j) \asymEq{(n/b^j)^{\log_b a}}
\opnohint\then
    \sum^{\log_b n-1}_{j=0} a^j f(n/b^j) \asymEq{\sum^{\log_b n-1}_{j=0}a^j\left(n/{b^j}\right)^{\log_b a}}
\endcalc$$

What they implicitly use here are two properties of asymptotic notation that they don't even seem to mention in Chapter 3, "Growth of functions".  For the first step, they use the fact that
$$
\tag{0}
f(x) \asymLe{g(x)} \;\then\; f(h(x)) \asymLe{g(h(x)}
$$ if $\;h(x) \to \infty\text{ for }x \to \infty\;$.  And for the second step they use
$$
\tag{1}
f(x) \asymLe{g(x)} \;\then\; \sum_{i \in V(x)}{k_i\,f(x)} \asymLe{\sum_{i \in V(x)}{k_i\,g(x)}}
$$ if $\;\langle \forall i :: k_i \ge 0\rangle\;$.

(Note how $\Ref{0}$ and $\Ref{1}$ immediately imply the corresponding $\Theta$ versions by writing $\Theta$ in terms of twice $O$.  I switched to $O$ to simplify the proofs that follow.)

With that, I'm assuming that you see how these properties prove the correctness of Cormen et al.'s reasoning.  In the rest of this answer I will prove both properties.

## Notation

But first, some notes on notation.  I'm using some notations inspired by Dijkstra et al.: see, e.g., [EWD1300](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html).  The main difference is writing $\;\langle \forall x : D(x) : P(x) \rangle\;$ where one usually writes $\;(\forall x)(R(x) \then P(x))\;$ for "for all $\;x\;$ such that $\;D(x)\;$ we have $\;P(x)\;$"; and similarly writing $\;\langle \exists x : R(x) : P(x) \rangle\;$ instead of $\;(\exists x)(R(x) \land P(x))\;$.  $\;R(x)\;$ is called the *range* of $\;x\;$, and if the range is understood from the context then it is left out, to reduce the burden on the reader.

Let me also introduce an abbreviation that helps me a lot in dealing with asymptotic notation, which is the 'for all large enough' quantifier: $$
\langle \forallle x :: P(x) \rangle \;\equiv\; \langle \exists y :: \langle \forall x : x \ge y : P(x) \rangle \rangle
$$ which has properties similar to $\;\exists\;$ and $\;\forall\;$, e.g., $$
\langle \forall x :: P(x) \then Q(x) \rangle \;\then\; (\langle \forallle x :: P(x) \rangle \then \langle \forallle x :: Q(x) \rangle)
$$

Using this abbreviation, we can write Cormen et al.'s definition of $O$ as
$$
f(x) \asymLe{g(x)} \;\equiv\; \langle \exists c : c\gt0: \langle \forallle x :: 0 \le f(x) \le c\,g(x) \rangle \rangle
$$ (where $\;c\;$ ranges over $\;\mathbb R\;$) and $$
h(x) \to \infty\text{ for }x \to \infty \;\equiv\; \langle \forall y :: \langle \forallle x :: h(x) \ge y \rangle \rangle
$$ Personally I find both right hand sides simpler to read and work with.

Also, let me make clear that I'm leaving the range of $\;x,y,z\;$ unspecified in this answer: it could for example be Cormen et al.'s 'exact powers of $\;b\;$', or $\;\mathbb N\;$, or $\;\mathbb R\;$.

## The first property

Now to prove property $\Ref{0}$, we start with its right hand side, and expand the definitions:

$$\calc
    f(h(x)) \asymLe{g(h(x)}
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $O$}
    \langle \exists c : c\gt0: \langle \forallle x :: 0 \le f(h(x)) \le c\,g(h(x)) \rangle \rangle
\op\when\hint{by $\Ref{2}$ using $\;h(x) \to \infty\text{ for }x \to \infty\;$, see below}
    \langle \exists c : c\gt0: \langle \forallle x :: 0 \le f(x) \le c\,g(x) \rangle \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $O$}
    f(x) \asymLe{g(x)}
\endcalc$$

where the middle step follows from $$
\tag{2} \langle \forallle x :: P(x) \rangle \then \langle \forallle x :: P(h(x)) \rangle
$$ if $\;h(x) \to \infty\text{ for }x \to \infty\;$.

We prove $\Ref{2}$ as follows.  Assuming $\;h(x) \to \infty\text{ for }x \to \infty\;$, i.e., $\;\langle \forall y :: \langle \forallle x :: h(x) \ge y \rangle \rangle\;$, we calculate

$$\calc
    \langle \forallle x :: P(x) \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{expand abbreviation $\;\forallle\;$}
    \langle \exists y :: \langle \forall x : x \ge y : P(x) \rangle \rangle
\op\then\hint{choose $\;x:=h(x)\;$ -- to introduce $\;P(h(x))\;$}
    \langle \exists y :: \langle \forall x : h(x) \ge y : P(h(x)) \rangle \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{add the assumption for this specific $\;y\;$}\hint{-- this is the only thing we know about $\;h(x) \ge y\;$}
    \langle \exists y ::
            \langle \forallle x :: h(x) \ge y \rangle
            \land
            \langle \forall x : h(x) \ge y : P(h(x)) \rangle
     \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{expand abbreviation $\;\forallle\;$}
    \langle \exists y,z ::
            \langle \forall x : x \ge z : h(x) \ge y \rangle
            \land
            \langle \forall x : h(x) \ge y : P(h(x)) \rangle
     \rangle
\op\then\hints{logic: $\;\then\;$ is transitive; remove superfluous $\;\exists y\;$}\hint{-- since this brings us immediately to our goal}
    \langle \exists z :: \langle \forall x : x \ge z : P(h(x)) \rangle \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{abbreviation $\;\forallle\;$}
    \langle \forallle x :: P(h(x)) \rangle
\endcalc$$

This completes the proof of $\Ref{2}$ and therefore of $\Ref{0}$.

## The second property

For property $\Ref{1}$ we again start with the right hand side, expand the definitions, and work towards the left hand side:

$$\calc
    \sum_{i \in V(x)}{k_i\,f(x)} \asymLe{\sum_{i \in V(x)}{k_i\,g(x)}}
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $O$}
    \langle \exists c : c\gt0: \langle \forallle x :: 0 \le \sum_{i \in V(x)}{k_i\,f(x)} \le c\,\sum_{i \in V(x)}{k_i\,g(x)} \rangle \rangle
\op\when\hint{arithmetic -- simplify the sums away}
    \langle \exists c : c\gt0: \langle \forallle x :: \langle \forall i : i \in V(x) : 0 \le k_i\,f(x) \le c\,k_i\,g(x) \rangle \rangle \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{divide by $\;k_i\;$ using the assumption that $\;\langle \forall i :: k_i \ge 0 \rangle\;$}
    \langle \exists c : c\gt0: \langle \forallle x :: \langle \forall i : i \in V(x) : 0 \le f(x) \le c\,g(x) \rangle \rangle \rangle
\op\when\hint{logic: remove unused quantification}
    \langle \exists c : c\gt0: \langle \forallle x :: 0 \le f(x) \le c\,g(x) \rangle \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $O$}
    f(x) \asymLe{g(x)}
\endcalc$$

This proves $\Ref{1}$.

$%
\endgroup
%$

Comment: I'd been planning this answer for a long time already, my apologies that it took so long.  Hopefully it adds some understanding-- I've used notations that I'm used to, since that seemed the only way I could get the proofs across clearly.  Let me know if there are parts which I should clarify.